# Theorem Proof for "The number 0 times a vector is 0"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

From Linear Algebra Done Right, the first theorem for vector spaces is the title of the question. I follow the mechanics of the proof in the book which employs the distributive property, but as someone who did not fully grasp the technical details of mathematical proofs from early education, I'm very confused about this use of the distributive property.

Specifically, why does this make sense? As a full time Software Engineer, why not just define this operation as an axiom or a given? I guess the meta question is how and when do we choose to define an axiom? I assume we draw the line because proofs that build off this don't work?

EDIT: The proof from the book,
For $a\in F$, we have
$a0 = a(0+0) = a0 + a0$

Comment: Could you provide the proof?

Comment: Generally, the less axioms the better. Any assumed truth which is derivable from others is redundant.

Comment: Added proof if that helps.

Comment: "The number $0$ times a vector" is not a theorem! Do you mean "The number $0$ times a vector equals the zero vector"? I'm not just nit-picking $-$ this is exactly the sort of thing that you have to be careful about when learning about proofs.

Comment: @TonyK The book states that it's a Theorem, I'm not sure if the book is incorrect.

Comment: viki, "The number $0$ times a vector" is not even a statement, so how can it be a theorem? It can certainly be the heading of a paragraph that goes on to state and prove a theorem, but obviously it can't be a theorem in its own right.

Comment: I've fixed the title.

Comment: @DavidPeterson: What you said is **generally wrong**. Propositional logic can be expressed using "⇒" and "⊥" as the only connectives, and [Lukasiewicz found a 1-sentence axiom schema for that calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicational_propositional_calculus#Axiom_system). In mathematics, minimalism is almost always the wrong approach. Instead, one should look for key structural properties.

Comment: Another example is PA. Many people think that the one involving the successor function is the 'right one', but it is not. Its axiomatization as [PA− plus induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations) is in fact the right way to think about PA. From an algebraic perspective, it is obvious; PA axiomatizes minimal initial segments of discrete ordered semi-rings. Later on reverse mathematics highlighted even more the importance of PA−.

Comment: @viki.omega9: While the answer you got isn't wrong, your concern from a software engineer viewpoint is indeed meaningful, contrary to what many people might tell you. It doesn't matter if you don't fully understand the two examples I gave above, but the point is simply that minimizing axioms should never be the true goal of mathematics or formalization of mathematics. Even the example of PA−, which was taken from Kaye according to wikipedia, has axiom 6 stating that $0·x = 0$ for every $x$, which is redundant as per the footnote. Why then did Kaye include it? Who knows? Algebraic elegance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would only need to add an axiom specifying the behavior of multiplication by $0$ if it didn't already follow from the axioms that $0v=0$. Since it does, there's no reason to specify this.

You seem to be worried about whether the axioms handle $0$ "correctly." They do, and the proof you describe shows this. It shows that, given the axioms in the book, $0v=0$ for all $v$. Once you've proven this, you accept it as a fact and never have to worry about it again.

An analogy is to think about what would happen if you wanted to add an axiom that handles $2$ "correctly," namely
$$2v = v+v$$
Why not specify this as an axiom? Well, we can prove this too.
$$2v = (1+1)v = v+v$$
Do we have to specify that multiplication by any positive integer is repeated addition? No, this follows from the distributive law, so there's no need to add it as an axiom.

Comment: Thanks! I think the clarification to find the minimum set of axioms that help prove other theorems/properties is what helped!

Comment: @viki Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is in principle possible to add things as axioms that are redundant. It is actually not uncommon not to have absolutely minimal descriptions for various reasons, such as to be more clear or more intuitive.

That said, there is a price to having more axioms. If you want to show that some structure is a vector space, then you have to check *all the axioms are verified.* Thus, if you add redundant axioms to your list you add extra work down the road, each and every time you want to check that something is a vector space.

I don't know much about software development but maybe this analogy makes sense. If you want to test something and cover all possibilities, then you can either think hard to have good test case or think less hard and have more test. What is preferable will depend on various circumstance.

Comment: I think the part that I'm confused about with the definition is that why not defined scalar multiplication with the zero as a special case? Your answer is very interesting with the exploding number of states the software system can take. There is no principled way to enforce fewer axioms or piece-wise definitions. Therefore it's very subjective. My point with what I'm reading in the book is that it's unclear why we had to make it a theorem, and I guess per your answer as a student I just have to go along with it.

Comment: There is no reason. I am pretty sure there are books that take $0v=0$ as axiom. But if you then want to show that, say, the real polynomials are a real vector space (with the usual operations) then you have to write an extra line that. $0P = 0 $ is indeed true. The point is there is the abstract notion of vector space, but then you want to deal with concrete objects and see if they are vector spaces and for those concrete objects the operation are already given. And there it is a small extra burden to check.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove and not define that $0v =0 $ for any vector $v$ because multiplication by scalars is already defined for a given vector space. You cannot redefine $0v$ to be something else unless that value match with the value given by our scalar multiplication which in this case, turns out to be $0$.

Regarding the axiom part, we always try to choose a system with the least number of axioms needed to achieve what we require, and these axioms, of course should not seem to contradict each other. Again in your case, since distibutive property already gives you a value for $0v$,  defining $0v$ to be another than $0$ is just a contradiction and defining it to be $0$ is just redundant.

Comment: Can you tell me we cannot start with a definition that handles the 0 case correctly?

Comment: You can, here, define it to be zero. There is nothing actually 'wrong' with that. But what we mean is it absolutely pointless to do so because even if you do so, you are required to check that it matches with the value obtained from the other axioms which basically amounts to doing the proof that you already mentioned.  This, thus, helps in no way except to add one more statement to our axioms.We are still supposed to do the proof you mentioned, though however, this time, the reason to do it is to show the value matches with the value from the other axioms rather than for finding out the value

Answer (score 0):

We *define* $0$ as a value where $a+0=a$ and have an axiom to assume such a number exists.  We have no reason assume that this number $0$ has any *other* magical properties.

We could write an axiom that there is some soul-crushing number $\Omega$ with the property $\Omega\cdot a = 0$ or maybe some blob all-smothering number $\Xi$ where $\Xi\cdot a = \Xi$.  But we have no reason to think those might be the same number that has magical additive identity property.  And it'd be *really* poor axiomatic system building to make an axiom that a necessary magical number has two *different* magical properties.

(Now I suppose it is moot to argue why we have axioms for some magic properties but not others.  It seems useful and aesthetic that we have magical identity numbers where $a+0=a$ and $1*a = a$, but it *doesn't* seem necessary that why have a soul-eating number where $\Omega\cdot a=0$ or a blob-smothering number where $\Xi\cdot a = \Xi$.  Why not?  I dont know.  It doesn't really seem to build a system I find necessary.)

(Not to mention such numbers are inconsistent.  $\Omega\cdot 1 = 0$ because $\Omega$ is the soul-crusher.  But $\Omega\cdot 1 = \Omega$ because $1$ is the multiplicative identity.  And $\Xi\cdot \Omega = 0$ because $\Omega$ is the soul-crusher but $\Xi\cdot \Omega = \Xi$ because $\Xi$ is the smotherer.)

More to the point, we have a property relating $+$ to $\times$ of distribution that all $a\cdot(b + c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c$.  It is more powerful and enlightening and humbling to realize that these are forces larger than ourselves, that such a relationship *must* yield the result that $a\cdot 0 = a(0+0)= a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$ so we must have that $a\cdot 0 = 0$ and $0$ although only defined to be an additive identity *must*, whether we want it or not, must also be a the multiplicative soul-crusher.